# .htaccess rewriting a URL which is passing 2 parameters

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

assume that i'm having a URL like this

**testingQuiz.com/my_test_link.php?id=4&name=test**

Now I need to rewrite the above URL like this,

**testingQuiz.com/4/test.html**

My question is, how can I achieve that by .htaccess URL rewriting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following perhaps should work, this is not fully tested btw but preliminary tests show it does as expected - though perhaps the second style redirect could be refined.

```
/* turn on url rewriting */
RewriteEngine On
/* set the level for the rewriting, in this case the document root */
RewriteBase /

/* match 2 parameters in querystring - the first is numeric and the second is alphanumeric with certain other common charachters */
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ my_test_link.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

That should allow you to write your urls / links in the form `http://www.example.com/23/skidoo.html` and for the `$_GET` variables to be interpreted as:

```
$_GET['id'] => 23, $_GET['name'] => skidoo
```

If you need to automagically redirect the user from your original style querystring to the new, nicer style url you could try adding the following after the rule above:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:my_test_link\.php)?\?id=([^&\s]+)&name=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2\.html? [R=302,L,NE]
```

That way, if a user enters the url `http://www.example.com?id=23&name=skidoo` it will redirect to `http://www.example.com/23/skidoo.html`